# How to make JS breakpoints work in VS2022 Python Flask project?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, debugging, visual-studio-2022

I have Python Flask project and some JS files in **static** directory. Breakpoints in JS are never hit at runtime. And I have scripts debugging enabled in VS, yet breakpoints are skipping. Breakpoints circles are marked with red color as usual (nothing is said about they isn't loaded or similar to that).

I tried using Firefox, MS Edge, IE 11.

I tried attaching VS debugger to firefox.exe

Nothing helps. Is it general VS problem? I don't understand what's wrong...

Comment: My bad, I read it wrong.